# Managing Model alias names

Tags: sequelize.js

Currently, the Sequelize models accept custom alias objects:

```
Parent.hasMany(Child, { as: { singular: string; plural: string;}})
```

for the one-to-many and many-to-many while the one-to-one relationships only accepts a single string alias:

```
Dad.hasOne(Mum, { as: 'Mummy'})
```

Attempting to apply the custom alias object to a one-to-one relationship throws an Inflection.js error.

```
Dad.hasOne(Mum, { as: { singular: 'Mummy', plural: 'Mummies' }})

D:\Projects\Sequelize\node_modules\inflection\lib\inflection.js:594
        var ignore = ( inflector.indexOf( skip, str.toLowerCase()) > -1 );

TypeError: str.toLowerCase is not a function
    at Object._apply_rules (D:\Projects\Sequelize\node_modules\inflection\lib\inflection.js:594:53)
    at Object.singularize (D:\Projects\Sequelize\node_modules\inflection\lib\inflection.js:692:24)
    at Object.singularize (D:\Projects\Sequelize\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:285:21)
    at new HasOne (D:\Projects\Sequelize\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\has-one.js:45:37)
    at Function.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Sequelize\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:92:25)
    at Function.Dads.associate.models [as associate] (D:\Projects\Sequelize\dist\models\schema\Dad.js:17:20)
```

My current implementation utilises underscores for table names, since it makes distinguishing table ownership in a microservice very clear:

```
Service_User
Service_Permission
Service_Activity
```

and I access it through the models object directly:

```
connection = new Sequelize();

models: {
  Service_User: connection.import(path/to/schema)
  Service_Permission: connection.import(path/to/schema)
  Service_Activity: connection.import(path/to/schema)
}

models.Service_User.create({});
```

The problem that I am facing is that I am unable to predict what the accessor names are.

Is there any way that I can either:

1. Derive the accessor name from the models.

```
This can be done by not utilising alias:

Dad.hasOne(Mum);

const dad = models.Dad.findOne(...);

// dad.getMum()
// is this legal, definitely not safe right?!
const mum = dad.[`get${models.Dad.options.name.singular}`]();
```

2. Utilise some kind of structure that removes the guesswork.

```
const MumAlias = { singular: 'Mummy', plural: 'Mummies' };

MumsClub.hasMany(Mum, { as: MumAlias })
Dad.hasOne(Mum, { as: MumAlias })

const mumsClub = models.MumsClub.findOne(...);
const dad = models.Dad.findOne(...);

// dad.getMummy()
const mum = dad[`get${MumAlias.singular}`];

// mumsClub.setMummies()
mumsClub[`set${MumAlias.plural}`]([mum1, mum2, mum3, ...]);
```